# Why does Firefox behave differently on collapsing margins?

Tags: html, css

Firefox renders a 100px margin at the top of `div.p`. It seems to be a margin collapse. But the computed height of `div.p` is 100px. According to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins) it should not do margin collapse. Is it a bug, or am I wrong here? Chrome renders as expect.
[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqRNjx)

```css
.s {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background: yellow;
  float: left;
}
.p {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  zoom: 1;
}
.p:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="p">
  <div class="s"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what it is, but it doesn't happen if you remove the `float:left`, so I don't think it's a collapsing margin.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with the margin-bottom creating an overflow, if we add `*{overflow:auto}`, the problem doesn't occur anymore : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGxWVB

Comment: I  can understand why if we `*{overflow:auto}`,problem doesn't occur anymore because it create a BFC.

Comment: Your problem isn't replicated in your code snippet for me. Both Chrome and FF are the same output. I'm running Firefox 46.0

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the traditional clearfix is not working, but here are three ways that do:

Like Kaiido said a `*{overflow:auto;}` works just fine to fix the issue.  This also works as `*{overflow:hidden;}`.

If you don't want a blanket overflow, you can be more precise by putting `overflow:hidden` or `overflow:auto` to just `.p`.  This also fixes the issue.

Finally, if you change `display: block` to `display: table` in your clearfix (`.p:after`), the issue also goes away.

I'm really not sure why the traditional clearfix is not working, but it isn't too hard to work around.